# Как отправлять изображения через WinForms C# боту телеграмм?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Хочу отправить картинку  боту по нажатию кнопки, но ничего не происходит. Даже ошибок. Что я могу делать не так?

```
string URL_img = "https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/541197-steam-logo-640x360.jpg";

using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(URL_img, FileMode.Open))
{
   Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend fts = new Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend();
   fts.Content = stream;
   fts.Filename = Path.GetFileName(URL_img);
   botclient.SendPhotoAsync(channel, fts, fts.Filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так открыть файл не получится.

```
       var stream = System.IO.File.Open(URL_img, FileMode.Open)
```

Можно попробовать что-то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223311/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-system-io-stream-object)

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("url here");
using (Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{

}
```

Comment: Периодически программа просто не может, видимо, достучаться до сервера телеграмм. Не приходит информация о боте. Возможно, виновата прокся, однако, я даже не получаю ошибок. Просто ничего не происходит

Comment: @BearHeaven Странно, я с таким не сталкивался.